# При десериализации даты прибавляются три часа времени

Tags: java, jackson

Есть такой вот класс:

```
@Data
public class RouteMessage {

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm")
    private Date expire;
    private Direct direct;
    private Map<String, Object> data;

}
```

При десериализации получаю ошибочную дату:

```
@Test
public void testMapper() throws IOException {

    RouteMessage routeMessage = new ObjectMapper().readValue("{\n" +
            "\t\"expire\": \"2017-06-26 15:00\",\n" +
            "\t\"direct\": \"EMAIL_TEMPLATE\"}", RouteMessage.class);
    System.out.println(routeMessage.getExpire());

}


Mon Jun 26 18:00:00 MSK 2017
```

Не могу понять почему прибавились 3 часа (скорее всего из-за часового пояса) и как убрать это ?

Answer (score 1):

У вас время в 12-часовом формате, а вы пишите 15:00.
Посмотрите внимательнее формат форматирования даты/времени [java.text.SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Поменял аннотацию на такую `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")` - ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Наверное по умолчанию используется временная зона GMT, если её не указывать. Попробуйте при указании даты/времени указать временную зону. `pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm z"` а параметр передавать в формате `2017-06-26 15:00 MSK`